# Oculus only Low FPS (UE4)

Tags: rendering, frame-rate, unreal-engine4, oculus

I am experiencing a weird issue developing with Unreal Engine 4.

I have a scene, containing some transparent object, forward rendering, using a second render camera (render to texture) that is 90fps proof on Vive, WMR, but is ~60fps using Oculus. Even weirder, I reduce GPU usage and it becomes 90fps in editor but is still ~60fps in shipping.

Do you have some hints about this Oculus only performance issue?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of what is basically forced vsync in the headset, you are locked into integer fractions of 90hz. (2/3-60hz, 1/2-45hz, 1/3-30hz, etc). When frametimes are too high to maintain 90hz, the frame rate steps down to 60hz for at least a few frames.

You might be right on the edge of performance for your app. You can verify this with the *STAT UNIT* or *STAT DETAILED* console commands.

There might be extra CPU performance overhead for the Oculus‘ tracking software.

Comment: It look's like there is extra CPU/GPU overhead for the Oculus tracking software...